# iOS Black Screen with The 'Passive' connection 'App' access to protected services is denied

Tags: ios7

A handful of of users are experiencing a black screen and then a crash upon launching Pocketpedia. So far only users with iPod Touches running iOS 7.1 are reporting the issue. There is no crash log but the console shows:

```
kernel[0] <Debug>: launchd[141] Container: /private/var/mobile/Applications/48588222-6651-47F1-8BE9-5A59DACA3B84 (sandbox)
backboardd[28] <Error>: HID: The 'Passive' connection 'Pocketpedia3' access to protected services is denied.
wifid[15] <Notice>: WiFi:[417568384.004526]: BG Application: Not Present, BG Daemon: Present. Daemons: dataaccessd apsd MobileMail sharingd 
com.apple.launchd[1] (UIKitApplication:com.bruji.pocketpedia3[0x4b17][141]) <Notice>: (UIKitApplication:com.bruji.pocketpedia3[0x4b17]) Exited: Killed: 9
backboardd[28] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.bruji.pocketpedia3[0x4b17]' quit with signal 9: Killed: 9
```

Other developers have reported a similar issue with iAd and iCloud. But Pocketpedia does not use any Apple service and they are all off on both the “App ID” in the Apple Certificate Console as well as under Xcode capabilities. Location services are also not used.

Does anyone know the underling issue or possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with the passive connection is unrelated to the black screen issue. Setting the default storyboard via the user interface in Xcode sets the following two Info.plist keys.

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~iphone</key>
<string>MainStoryboard</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile~ipad</key>
<string>MainStoryboard-iPad</string>
```

The fix is to edit the Info.plist and explicitly add the base name to be used on the iPod or the "~ipod" version key.

```
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>MainStoryboard</string>
```